# Android Kotlin Sharing data with screen on/off intentfilter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)

        val filter = IntentFilter()
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)
        // Here I want to send some data to MyBroadcastReceiver like .putExtra but how with IntentFilter???
        registerReceiver(MyBroadcastReceiver(), filter)

        return START_STICKY
    }
```

I need to send a variable using IntentFilter like we do with intent.putExtra when Screen On/Off happens. 
I have tried sending data separately but because of broadcast object get killed, all its variables reset.

```
class MyBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    private var isRemoteOn: Boolean = false
    private var pinNo = "-1"

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if(intent.action.equals("is_remote_on")) {
            var status = intent.extras?.get("status").toString()
            isRemoteOn = if (status.equals("on")) true else false
            Log.d("RemoteOnOff", isRemoteOn.toString())
        }
         else if(intent.action.equals("setPin")) {
            Log.d("PinNo", pinNo.toString());
            pinNo = intent.extras?.get("pinNo").toString();
        }
        else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) or intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
         Log.d("pinNo", pinNo.toString())   // This always -1 when Screen get on/off no matter what I set here
         Log.d("isRemoteOn", isRemoteOn.toString())   // This always false when Screen get on/off even I have set it to true           }
    }
}
```

here is how I tried to set isRemoteOn and pinNo

```
val broadcastIntent = Intent()
broadcastIntent.action = "setPin"
broadcastIntent.putExtra("pinNo", "5")
broadcastIntent.setClass(this, MyBroadcastReceiver::class.java)

val broadcastIntent2 = Intent()
broadcastIntent2.action = "is_remote_on"
broadcastIntent2.putExtra("status", "on")
broadcastIntent2.setClass(this, MyBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON` and `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` will be send by Android System, there are no way for you to add info to intent when `BroadcastReceiver` trigger callback `onReceive`. About Problem, I recommend you save some info about pinNo and isRemoteOn to `SharedPreferences`. inside `onReceive` you get it through `SharedPreferences`